# Format all values in a dynamic value range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a start value of `500` in I20. This represents a monthly installment. This installment increases every 12 months at a fixed rate, which is placed in C9 (e.g. `3%`). These installments are written into Column I. To calculate this, I have a helper column E which starts with `0` and is incremented by `1` every twelve rows. Also in column I are values which are calculated differently.

I want all values in column I which fall into this specific value range [(=`500 * (1+C9)^E20`) = (e.g. `500`, `530,45`, `546,36` etc.)] to be formatted in a special way.

What does the formula for the conditional formatting in I20 have to look like so that I can apply it to the entire column?

[image]

Comment: if you highlight from I20 down (specifically I20), then the formula you have should work - just fix the C9 in place - `=(500 * (1+$C$9)^E20)`

Comment: @SeanC Yeah, I tried that but it didn't work as e.g. when I click into I28 and take a look at the conditional formatting formula it still says: `=500 * (1+$C$9)^E20`, instead of `=500 * (1+$C$9)^E28`

Comment: @pnuts: n represents the value in column `E`

Comment: @coala, yes it will. the formula always shows the first cell in the range, not the cell you have highlighted. If I clear the formatting from cells I20:i27, then I28 will show `=(500 * (1+$C$9)^E28)` as the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select I20:I35 HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=I20=500*(1+C$9)^E20
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK:

I chose blue fill:

[image: SO33180072 example]

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that's it. Key was to reference I20 in the formula, I see. Good stuff!

Comment: I agree. Good editing and I will remember to "code" values/formulas rather than cell references for upcoming questions/replies.